# Can we Integrate AFNetworking in Enterprise level iOS Applications

Tags: ios, ios7, ios5, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am a newbie here and I am developing a new iOS Application and wanted to know whether we can implement `AFNetworking` in my iOS Enterprise application instead of using Apple's Own NSURL because if `AFNetworking 2.0` is deprecated. Do I need to change back all the networking code to `NSURL`.

Comment: You can use any library you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFNetworking is released under the MIT License. Which means you can use it as you like, enterprise or not. Modify and so on. The dev is a great dude.

You can read AFNetworking's license here:
[License File](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/LICENSE)